IV with uncommon treatment and implausibly large effects
I am working on an instrumental variables strategy where I have an uncommon binary treatment (less than 1% of the sample is treated). I have a binary instrument that is switched on for around 85% of the treated group and 45% of the untreated group. My outcome variable is continuous.
In my second stage regression, I am getting coefficients that seem implausibly large. I have tried different approaches in R to deal with the non-linearity in my treatment (like using a probit to predict treatment and using that as the instrument or using the treatReg function in the sampleSelection package). However, the problem persists.
I think the issue could be because the second stage regresses the outcome on the predicted values of treatment which are very small (in all cases) because of how uncommon treatment is. I.e., the predicted probability of treatment goes from 1% to 3% when the instrument is switched from off to on. However, the coefficient on treatment in the second stage represents the change in outcome arising from a full one unit shift in treatment probability (going from 0 to 100%). However, this is extrapolating from the limited variation in treatment probability that (1 to 3% change).
Does anyone have any advice or thoughts on how to interpret such results and whether there is any way to scale the coefficients etc.? Also, it is very possible I am completely missing something in my understanding of IV!
Here is an example of what the coefficients look like:
Outcome = test score (out of 100)
intercept = 65.00
treatment_pred. = -80.00
In this case, if someone is "treated", they would have a negative score. But because that treated variable is predicted probability of treatment status, no one actually has a negative score because their coefficient is downscaled by the value of treatment_pred (which is somewhere between 0 and 3%). Again, I think this has something to do with the small (but highly significant) coefficient in the first stage.
Thanks so much!
